# How to add a equal-aspect inset axes in the corner of a parent axes

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to add an inset axis to the upper left corner of a parent axis. This can easily be done like so:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
iax = ax.inset_axes([0,.8, .2, .2])
```

[image: inset_axes]

However, I need the inset axis `iax` to have an aspect ratio of one. But when I change the aspect ratio, the inset axis shifts slightly to the right.

```
iax.set_aspect('equal')
```

[image: offset equal aspect inset axis]

How can I make the aspect ratio of the inset axis "equal", while still having it nestled in the upper left corner? I know I could just mess around with the inset_axes location parameter, but ideally I want some method that works for any given axis size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the [anchor](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_anchor.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_anchor) parameter as follows:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
iax = ax.inset_axes([0, .8, .2, .2])
iax.set_aspect('equal', anchor="NW")
plt.show()
```

[image]